# Not able to open Modal dialog in Chrome

Tags: visualforce, popup, browser, chrome

In my Visual force page when clicking on a lookup icon, I need to open a popup window to select list of available options.So I need to retrieve the value from the child window

Am using the following line of code to open a popup.

```
window.showModalDialog('/apex/CustomCausalityLookup', passvalue, 'dialogHeight:450px; dialogWidth:700px;');
```

it is working as expected in FireFox,IE & Safari but in Chrome pop up is not coming.(I have checked the Chrome browser settings and checked Allow popup option ...)
While clicking on the link in Chrome am getting the following error in developer console

[image]

The errors are,

**Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function  AddNewCause?retURL=%2Fa05%2Fl%3FretURL%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fc.na15.visual.force.com%252Fapex%252FS…:76
opencausalitylookup     AddNewCause?retURL=%2Fa05%2Fl%3FretURL%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fc.na15.visual.force.com%252Fapex%252FS…:76
onclick     AddNewCause?retURL=%2Fa05%2Fl%3FretURL%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fc.na15.visual.force.com%252Fapex%252FS…:12**

Any idea..??

Thanks 
Chitra

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Chrome has stopped supporting Model dialog box [More](http://windowsitpro.com/blog/google-kills-showmodaldialog-api-chrome-37-and-does-evil-exchange-owa). You will have to replace your model dialog boxes with window.open in order to make it working in goggle chrome.

If you want to make inactive your parent window at the time of popup being open , you can use JQuery for that.

I have recently made these changes  in my project as well.

You can open popup using below code -

1)

> window.open('Page URL'+ '?ParameterName'+
>   ParameterValue,"","scrollbars=1,resizable=1,Width=1420px,Height=400px,Top=180,Left=80");

2) If you want to make read only parent window then can write below code on popup window -

> $(document).ready(function() { window.opener.blockUI(); })

3) If you want to make parent editable on cancel clik of client window then you can write below code -

> //cancel button handler 
>               function cancelWindow()
>                   {
>                        window.opener.unBlockUI();
>                        window.close();
>                        return false;
>                   }
>                jQuery(window).bind(
>                   "beforeunload", 
>                   function() { 
>                       window.opener.unBlockUI();
>                   }
>               );

4) If you want to call some parent window function from child window then you can do something like below -

> window.opener.SetRole(roleId,rowNo); // SetRole is parent window
>   function. You can also update parent window variable as well.

I have not tested syntax so might be some issue in syntaxes .

Comment: Thank you Pramod for your quick reply..I have wasted almost a day to fix..
Could you please elaborate your answer..I would appreciate if you give me any code samples...
If I open a window using window.open whether the child window will pass the selected message to the parent window...???
Please advice..Thanks

Comment: I have updated my post

Comment: Wow its awesome Pramod..
window.open('Page URL'+ '?ParameterName'+ ParameterValue,"","scrollbars=1,resizable=1,Width=1420px,Height=400px,Top=180,Left=80");
this syntax working like a charm..Am able to open a popup in Chrome and in all the browsers
also i need one advice from you..i need to select a value from child window and pass it to parent window..currently it returns empty value..
is there any parameter i need to mention to pass the value from child window..?

Comment: You can declare a variable on parent window java script like - var returnValue = ""; and can set this variable value from child window like - window.opener.returnValue ="xyz" based on your requirement.

Comment: Please up vote if it is helpful. You can also mark it best answer :)

Comment: Ya sure..I will be marking your response as answer..
parent window is not waiting for the child window to return value..
Is there any option to make parent window to wait for child window...??
I think am asking too many questions...thanks in advance

Comment: Javascript runs in Async mode therefore you are getting this behavior.  You can call a parent window function from child window as i have shown in my post. you can set a variable value like i have described in my comment and can use that variable in parent function and can do whatever u want in function.

Comment: You are awesome Pramod it was working as I expected...
Thank you so much..You saved my time,I was struggling with this..

Comment: Shall I ask one more doubt,,,,We have 4 to 5 lookup icon in the parent window..If user clicks one icon for more than one time / if user clicks all the icons at the same time they may get confuse....Is there any provision to lock the parent window once child window is opened...??
Thanks....

Comment: Yes found answer for that in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5660700/javascript-to-open-popup-window-and-disable-parent-window    post...

Answer (score 0):

As per Promod explanation i have used the following syntax to open the popup window

```
window.open('Page URL'+ '?ParameterName'+ ParameterValue,"","scrollbars=1,resizable=1,Width=1420px,Height=400px,Top=180,Left=80");
```

And then used **window.opener** to access parent window properties.